# Reduce an array of ints to an array of longest common prefixs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm dealing with zip codes, and I want to get the "Starts with" values from a list of zip codes.

For example, an array of

```rb
arr = [10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, 10006, 10007, 10008, 10009, 10010, 10011]
```

Should produce an array of:

```rb
out = [1000,10010,10011]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. The problem keeps getting bigger the more I think about it!

Edit1: Adding more examples
Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help so far, from the feedback from your comments, my question title may not be accurate.

What I want is the "Starts with" syntax that is commonly used in postage services. Basically if you have a fixed number of 5 digits (US post codes, without the zip+4), if a whole range is covered, e.g. 11000-11999 then it can be reduced to 11 in the starts with syntax. However, if there is a number (or set of numbers) in that range that is not included. e.g. 11005, then the syntax needs to return all of the numbers for that range until there is a common "starts with" again. So for that example, it would be:

```rb
[ 11000, 11001, 11002, 11003, 11004, 11006, 11001, 11007, 11008, 11009, 1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 1107, 1108, 1109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119 ]
```

So from 11000-11004 and 11006-11009, there is no common "starts with" numbers, so the exact numbers must be added. And from 11010 to 11999, the common numbers can be reduced as above.

Including letters in this syntax would be a massive bonus as that covers UK post codes as well. However this is harder as UK post codes are not always sequential, so I wasn't going to tackle that. 5 digit US zip codes.

Comment: Why would it return `10010` and `10011`? Those are the whole values as opposed to a prefix right?

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why wouldn't it return only 100? it's the common prefix of all number. If you want 4 digits, why wouldn't it return only 1000 and 1001? since 10010 and 10011 share the same prefix. Your example is not clear.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comments. CaTs your solution is almost right! Common zip code syntax is "Starts With" so if a zip code "starts with" 1000. It will match 10000-10009. However it must return 10010 and 10011, as 10012-10019 are not present. Therefore the starts with 1001 would match the wrong zip codes

Comment: I think you are not explaining your problem right, you don't want a list of prefixes, you want something like a regular expression to match all (and only) the elements of the array. But you are not giving proper context, what are the possible values, lengths and ranges? would you have letters? you should give more examples and explain it better.

Comment: You are right! Sorry about that. I've added another example. 5 digits, ints only, for a possible range of 00000-99999. Each zip code will be written out in full and I want to reduce it to the starts with context.

Comment: If you want to deal with UK postal codes in a similar way you should post a separate question. Among other things you would need to explain the format of those codes, and you should give a substantial example (`arr = [...]`) and show the desired return value (array) for that example. Assigning a variable to the array of UK postal codes, as I have done above (`arr = ...`) would be helpful as it would allow readers to refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it. Assigning variables to inputs is good practice whenever you include an example in a question.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
def doit(arr)
  a = arr.dup
  loop do
    size = a.size
    a = combine_by_last(a)
    break if a.size == size
  end
  a
end
```

```
def combine_by_last(a)
  b = []
  until a.empty?
    move_10 = a.first % 10 == 0 && a.size > 9 && a[9] == a.first + 9
    if move_10
      b << a.shift/10
      a.shift(9) # discard
    else
      b << a.shift
    end        
  end
  b
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, 10006, 10007, 10008, 10009,
       10010, 10011] +
       (11000..11999).to_a +
       [12251, 12252] +
       (12340..12349).to_a
```

```
doit arr
  #=> [1000, 10010, 10011, 11, 12251, 12252, 1234]
```

**Explanation**

The code reduces the array `arr` in stages, each involving sequences of 10 zip codes, the first ending in a zero, being replaced by the first of the 10 divided by `10`. The process terminates when no further reductions can be made. For example, if:

```
arr = (11000..11999).to_a
```

it would first be reduced to:

```
(1100..1199).to_a
```

then to:

```
(110..119)
```

then to:

```
11
```

We can modify `doit` to show this in action.

```
def doit(arr)
  a = arr.dup
  loop do
    size = a.size
    a = combine_by_last(a)
    puts
    p a 
    break if a.size == size
  end
  a
end
```

```
doit arr
  #=> [1000, 10010, 10011, 11, 12251, 12252, 1234]  

[1000,
 10010, 10011,
 1100, 1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 1107, 1108, 1109,
 1110, 1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119,
 1120, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1129,
 1130, 1131, 1132, 1133, 1134, 1135, 1136, 1137, 1138, 1139,
 1140, 1141, 1142, 1143, 1144, 1145, 1146, 1147, 1148, 1149,
 1150, 1151, 1152, 1153, 1154, 1155, 1156, 1157, 1158, 1159,
 1160, 1161, 1162, 1163, 1164, 1165, 1166, 1167, 1168, 1169,
 1170, 1171, 1172, 1173, 1174, 1175, 1176, 1177, 1178, 1179,
 1180, 1181, 1182, 1183, 1184, 1185, 1186, 1187, 1188, 1189,
 1190, 1191, 1192, 1193, 1194, 1195, 1196, 1197, 1198, 1199,
 12251, 12252,
 1234]

[1000, 
 10010, 10011,
 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119,
 12251, 12252,
 1234]

[1000,
 10010, 10011,
 11,
 12251, 12252,
 1234]
```

Because the zip codes are uniq and ordered, `a[9] == a.first + 9` is `true` if and only if `a[0]`, `a[1]`,...,`a[9]` are consecutive values.

The expression:

```
move_10 = a.first % 10 == 0 && a.size > 9 && a[9] == a.first + 9
```

could be simplified to:

```
move_10 = a.first % 10 == 0 && a[9] == a.first + 9
```

because if `a.size <= 9`, `a[9] == a.first + 9` would be become `nil == a.first + 9`, which would cause the condition to return `false`, as it should. This would, however, worsen readability.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerable's [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is useful for problems like this, it will group similar zipcodes together into a hash using some property they all have in common. In your case, we would want that property to be the prefix of the zipcode.

`group_by` takes a block that is used to map the item into a key, for example:

```
animals = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Donkey']

# Group each animal by their first letter
grouped_animals = animals.group_by {|animal| animal[0]} 

puts grouped_animals
# => {"C"=>["Cat"], "D"=>["Dog", "Donkey"]}
```

To group zip-codes by their prefixes, we can divide the number by 10 to drop the last digit. Then you can use the [`hash.keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-keys) to get only the prefixes.

```
zipcodes = [10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, 10006, 10007, 10008, 10009, 10010, 10011]
grouped_zipcodes = zipcodes.group_by {|zipcode| zipcode / 10}

puts grouped_zipcodes
# => {1000=>[10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, 10006, 10007, 10008, 10009], 1001=>[10010, 10011]}

puts grouped_zipcodes.keys
# => [1000, 1001]
```

This assumes your zipcodes are always 5 digits and that prefixes will always be the first 4  digits but at least now the problem is just reduced to figuring out how to want to find your prefix!

Comment: Suppose `zipcodes = (10000..10099).to_a`. As I understand, this would be represented by `[100]`, but you obtain `zipcodes.group_by {|zipcode| zipcode / 10}.keys #=>  [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009]`.  (You do get the correct answer if you divide by `100` rather than `10`, though `100` would be incorrect for other examples.). Now suppose that `zipcodes = [10000, 10001]`. You get `[1000]`, but that would require `10000` to be followed by all 9 consecutive values (`zipcodes = (10000..10009).to_a`). Here `[10000, 10001]` cannot be reduced. Peter, am I correct?